# How to calculate distance / thickness between two curved surfaces in 3D?

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry

I have two CSV files, each file contains list of 3D points include X, Y, and Z that represents a point in 3D space. The number of points in each file is not equal.
I write a program that reads points from CSV files and renders by OpenGL.
How can I measure the "distance / thickness (the space)" between two curved surfaces?

Are there any concepts / formulas about distance between two curved surfaces in 3D space?
Any keywords, theory, examples, illustrations, etc will help me very much.

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: First note that you don't have surfaces, but point clouds, which is not the same. And for a single distance to be uniquely defined, the two "surfaces" should be perfectly parallel.

Comment: For a first approach, triangulate one of the surfaces and for every point of the other, find the distance to the projection on the relevant triangle.